# Resize EditText (or view in general) to fill certain area of screen

Tags: android, resize, textview

in my current project I have a view with some textview in the upper third, an edittext in the middle and a button at the bottom, all taking roughly the same space. Now when I want to enter something in the edittext, the keyboard pops up and either the view is not resized, so the keyboard hides half of the edittext, which looks crappy, or the view is resized, shrinked to half its size, which looks...very... crappy. In the iphone version of my app I made it so when I tapped the edittext it would grow and enlarge, filling the whole view, so only the edittext and the keyboard are shown. The problem is, I have absolutely no clue how to do it in Android. I already rebuild my xml layout to use relativelayout instead of linearlayout, as I thought it would be easier.
Then I put the change in the onFocusChange method like so:

```
et = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etItems);
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {

        if(arg0==et) {
            if(arg1==true) {
                Log.i("EditText","got focus");
                enlargeEditText();
            } 
        } else {
            Log.i("EditText","lost focus");
        }

    }

});

private void enlargeEditText() {
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
   rllp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
   v.setLayoutParams(rllp);
}
```

The enlargeEditText method isnt final, I justed wanted to see if there is something changing, but...it isn't...instead I get :

```
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at de.lochmann.einkaufsliste.FragCreateList$1.onFocusChange(FragCreateList.java:88)
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:3938)
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:8465)
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at android.widget.EditText.onFocusChanged(EditText.java:136)
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:3760)
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5453)
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5403)
08-22 17:26:22.108: E/AndroidRuntime(20662):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:5381)
```

What's the problem? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: enlargeEditText(); So it's probably the way how I try to change the appearance of the view, but I don't know any other way.

Comment: Is this a NullPointerException? Where do you define `v`? Please post all of the logcat errors.

Comment: These are all logcat errors...no other exceptions. v is of course the reference to my inflated view. When I put it into onClick instead of OnFocusChange...nothing happens. No crash, but no result as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a ClassCastException. When you adjust the layout parameters of a view you must use the parent view's parameters. The view you want to manipulate is the RelativeLayout, but the parameters probably belong to FrameLayout. I don't know for certain because you have only posted *part* of your logcat.

This is a full LogCat trace:

```
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at org.whatever.example.Example.resize(Example.java:80)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at org.whatever.example.Example.access$0(Example.java:79)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at org.whatever.example.Example$1.onFocusChange(Example.java:66)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:2789)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7198)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:2612)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3767)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1152)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:1108)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1152)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:1108)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1152)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:1108)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1152)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:1111)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3718)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1285)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1957)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-22 12:23:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(12603):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

You should notice that at the top there is the exception: the cause of the problem, the most vital piece of information a LogCat can give you. Also you seemed to have skipped a couple lines because I'm unaware of how the line `enlargeEditText();` can compile but throw an exception...

**Anyway**

Simply change the LayoutParameters:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams rllp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
rllp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
v.setLayoutParams(rllp);
```

It would also be nice to see how `v` is defined in the LayoutInflater but I'm guessing that FrameLayout.LayoutParameters is the class that you want.

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for the great help. I am sorry about the thing with the logcat, I know what it is and normally I know how to read them, but I tried two times yesterday and it just gave me this short trace, now when I tried it today it gave me a full trace and it was indeed a classcastexception. Eclipse is strange at times. Additionally I now understand layoutparams much better. Thanks again :)